# How do $x^{p}+y^{p}=z^{p}$ and $x\equiv y \pmod{p}$ together imply $x\equiv -z \pmod{p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences

I am reading Marcus' *Number Fields* and I have been a little stuck following his argument in page $4$ (where he is sketching an argument for Case 1 of Fermat's Last Theorem for primes $p$ for which $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a UFD, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/p}$). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I don't understand how he deduces $x\equiv -z \pmod{p}$. It seems to be some basic congruence trick, but it is somehow evading me. I can use Fermat's Little Theorem to get $x+y\equiv z\pmod{p}$ from $x^{p}+y^{p}= z^{p} \pmod{p}$. Since $x\equiv y\pmod{p}$, this implies $2x=-z\pmod{p}$. But this is different from what Marcus claims, namely $x\equiv -z \pmod{p}$.

Could someone shed some light on my miserable confusion?

Comment: Fremat's Little Theorem :$$x^p\equiv x\pmod p$$ for all integer $x$ and prime $p$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Yes! Indeed, I tried to do in the post above. Where did I go astray?

Comment: Did you see exercises 16-28 for details? The claim is that if $ a^p + b^p = c^p$, then $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$. He applied that to $a = x, b = -z, c = -y$.

Comment: @Prism What is the next line in the screenshot? It ends on a comma, and the next sentence fragment could be useful.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Thanks for information. I didn't take a look for the exercises in detail (I guess I should have!) I have updated the screenshot.

Comment: @StellaBiderman That's a question for Marcus. He can proof it using any contradiction that he wants. Maybe this proof sheds more insight into other scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see exercises 16-28 for details?

I believe (might be wrong) the claim there is that if $a^p+b^p=c^p$, then we must have $a\equiv b \pmod p$. He applied that to $a=x, b=y, c=z$ first, and then to $a=x,b=−z,c=−y$.

Comment: Just for the record, the exercise is that if $x+\omega y=u\alpha^{p}\pmod{p}$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and $u$ is a unit, then $x\equiv y \pmod{p}$. Which is more or less what you said.

Answer (score 1):

The book seems to be incorrect. I fully agree with you're reasoning. Additionally, if we assume $x\cong -z$ Then it follows that $y\cong 2x\Rightarrow z\cong 3x$. But $z\cong -x$ so $4x\cong 0$ so $p|x$. This contradicts the assumption in the middle of the paragraph. Additionally, if you apply this to his chain equality we get $GCD(x,y)\geq p$, despite the fact that at the beginning we can say WLOG $GCD(x,y)=1$

Comment: Thanks Stella. I am happy that I haven't gone completely crazy… :-)

Comment: I'm trying to decide what to do with the chain equality. If the last bit is changed to $...=z^p=(-z)^p$ then it's true, though the rest of the proof might make this reading invalid. In any case, we can specifically note that the chain equality is wrong, because again taking the left and right terms tells us $p|x$

Comment: The contradiction that he arrives at is $ 2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, and presumably $p$ is greater than 3.

Comment: Then the entire proof is wrong, because the end of that chain equality isn't true and making it true doesn't give that contradiction.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this proof, assuming exercises 16-28 do what they are supposed to. There are many ways to reach a contradiction. The screenshot ends with a comma, and the next line is likely "which is a contradiction".

Comment: We are not making the "assume $x \equiv -z$". Instead, it should follow from exercises 16-28, similar to why $x \equiv y$.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Reading your comments make sense. Thanks! So he is reaching contradiction in a different way (using the result of exercises).

Comment: @StellaBiderman: I should have included the screenshot in full in the beginning. My apologies! :(